# Weka software decision tree

Tags: weka, decision-tree

After installing Weka 3.8, load a .csv file in the Explorer, I wanted to build a decision tree with the parameter "use training set".

Everything was installed ok (a self-extracting executable for 64-bit Windows that includes Oracle's 64-bit Java VM 1.8)

The file loaded fine as it was saved previously, using excel, as coma delimited.
The problem lays in building the decision tree itself: I go to the tab Classify, select the test option "use training set" and start.

After starting, appears a particular result which, accordingly to some images I've seen before, should allow, from there, to right-click and select "Visualize Tree".

That doesn't happen, as you can see in the next image:

[image]

How do I fix this in order to build the decision tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run a ZeroR classifier, see http://chem-eng.utoronto.ca/~datamining/dmc/zeror.htm. The ZeroR classifier is not a decission tree classifier and can not be visualised as such. You need to train an actual decission tree classifier, J48 is one of them. See http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/mobasher/classes/ect584/WEKA/classify.html for a guide on how to do so.

Comment: Oh ok, understandable. Appreciated for your time, help and guidance.
have a great day